# if Else statement inside for loop is not working

Tags: python

am using following code to check certain conditions

```
 for myarg in myargs:
    if myarg=='heading.png':
       t = find(dirpath + '\\' + myarg)
      t1= capture(t.getX() - 50, t.getY() + 50, t.getW(), t.getH())
      click(t1)

    else
    print "else inside-----------"
```

`myargs` conatians `heading.png,name.png etc`

while executing the above code am gettign erros `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: In your question, your indentation is wrong in so many places.

Comment: In Python, everything must be properly indented as the error is telling you. Everything after the `if` block should be at the same indentation until the `else` block at which point the block after the `else` should be indented equally to the `if` block

Comment: `:` is requiered after each block init, `else` included

Answer (score 8):

Fix your indentation, you're missing a colon after `else` and the following `print`-statement is not indented.

```
for myarg in myargs:
    if myarg=='heading.png':
        t = find(dirpath + '\\' + myarg)
        t1= capture(t.getX() - 50, t.getY() + 50, t.getW(), t.getH())
        click(t1)

    else:
        print "else inside-----------"
```

I advice using [`pylint`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint/1.1.0) or a similar syntax checker to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily from your error that there is indentation error.
Change your function to

```
for myarg in myargs:
    if myarg=='heading.png':
        t = find(dirpath + '\\' + myarg)
        t1= capture(t.getX() - 50, t.getY() + 50, t.getW(), t.getH())
        click(t1)
    else:      # here you must use colon
        print "else inside-----------"
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in `Python` is, simply put, the equivalent of `{}` in other languages like `C++` and `C#`.

**Don't** use text editors to write scripts, you can ***use*** rich editors for writing scripts.

```
   for myarg in myargs:
        if myarg=='heading.png':
              t = find(dirpath + '\\' + myarg)
              t1= capture(t.getX() - 50, t.getY() + 50, t.getW(), t.getH())
              click(t1)
       else:
              print "else inside-----------"
```