# indentationError in if else loop

Tags: python

while i trying to execute following code

```
for value in jsondata:
    command = value['command'] 
    val = value['value'] 
    print command
    print val

    if command=='sel_media':
        t = find(dirpath + '\\' + myarg)
        t1= capture(t.getX() - 50, t.getY() + 50, t.getW(), t.getH())
        click(t1)

    else:

        print "else inside-----------"
```

am getting

```
else:
^
indentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

i dont know why it is happening?
please correct me

Comment: Python differentiates between spaces and newlines, be consistent. I have this problem sometimes

Comment: I suspect it may be due to your if being indented with a tab and your else being indented with spaces

Comment: I suggested that you use [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) in [my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784740/if-else-statement-inside-for-loop-is-not-working/22784759#22784759). Pylint should give you a warning if you have mixed indentation of tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is probably mixing tabs and spaces for indentation.

Just set your editor to never use tabs. All decent programming editors have this option.

Comment: Go to `Settings | Preferences... | Language Menu/Tab Settings` and make sure `Replace by space` is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all `blank`s in your file ans spaces not `tab`. If you have `vim` editor you can check by `:set list` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due having a tab in your code somewhere. Python treating tabs as 8 spaces, but your editor is probably set up to display them as 4 spaces. try using `python -t` which will give you an error if you use a tab character.

Answer (score 0):

Set your code editor to use spaces instead of tabs and set those tabstops to 4. Python uses 4 spaces to differentiate between code blocks. Also you can try using sublime, it does this autoatically according to file types. You can also try to manually put 4 spaces and then wrtiting your code accordingly. Hope it helps.